# A question in comprehension

Tags: pronouns, paragraphs, comprehension

[image]

There was an English exam and it had this paragraph, I have two questions:

1. What does you in this sentence refer to?

   > it is usual as in China, to clean the whole house on the day before New Year, and to make sure you have paid any money **you** owe to others before midnight
2. from this sentence, which is the first Scottish New Year tradition? There isn't anything that shows the order

   > A lot of the New Year 'tradition' in countries like England, Australia and
   > the USA are actually Scottish in origin. These include joining hands ad singing the Scottish song Auld Lang Syne, Another custom which is less popular now, is 'first-footing'

Comment: Please explicitly write out the sentences you are concerned about, don't just add them as a picture. It is easier for other people to search for things if there is text to search!

Comment: I thought that since I mentioned the line that there won't be a need to write the sentence, should I add it then?

Comment: Yes please, you can just quote the specific parts you are concerned about. Use the "Quote" feature.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, in this case, what does You refer to? does it refer to a person in China? Or can we say the reader? Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'which is the first Scottish New Year tradition?' Is this the question in your exam? Depending on the wording of the question they may want you to give order the traditions occur in, or  which order the text gives. As a Scot, I can say, if you do housecleaning,  it is in the daytime of 31 December, paying debts I'm less sure, but the text says 'before midnight' so it is possible they expect you to 'bundle' this with the cleaning as one tradition. Auld lang Syne is sung *at the stroke* of midnight, First Footing happens after midnight.

Comment: the question literally says: The first Scottish New Year tradition is:

Comment: In that case, I would say that, you have an ambiguous question, since the order in which they are listed is not the order in which they would occur. (and the information on the order they happen is pretty much all in the text).

Comment: @YosefBaskin Fair enough, i focused on the fact that the cleaning and debt paying were stipulated as 'the day before' and 'before midnight' and lost site of the fact that the better known traditions didn't have their timing stipulated.

Comment: The *you* in boldface refers to the prior *you* in the standard font.

Comment: 1) *you* refers to a generic person - in more formal/accurate writing, *one* would be preferable and have the same meaning.  2) Joining hands and singing Auld Lang Syne is the only Scottish New Year tradition listed, and is the answer (the text refers to *these* but joining hands and singing can also be considered one bigger tradition).  The tradition of 'first-footing' in a separate paragraph, while also derived from Scottish traditions, is not a New Year tradition but instead a tradition for a new house.

Comment: Hmm.  It appears I am incorrect and 'first footing' is also a Scottish New Year tradition not a tradition for new houses.  In this case it is not clear which of these is *first*.  Is one of the options in the answer that neither is necessarily *first*?

Comment: The problem is this is what was in the exam, so I was wondering if I was missing something, or if there was anything that I haven't noticed

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions.

**You have paid any money you owe** assumes the word 'that': You in China repay money that you in China owe to others. The article compares cleaning house 'in China' to cleaning up personal obligations. Note also that the location is not Scotland.

**What is the first Scottish New Year tradition?** As far as order is concerned, the first one **listed** is singing Auld Lang Syne. That makes it the **correct** answer.

Such tests limit the answers to the text given (testing your reading comprehension), not your outside information (testing your general knowledge). 
For example, from the College Board's [SAT Test Readiness](https://collegereadiness.collegeboard.org/sat/inside-the-test/reading):

> - "Choices A and C are incorrect because they are not supported by the text."
> - "Answers are based only on the content stated in or implied by the passage."
> - "Find evidence in a passage...that best supports the answer."
> - "**Prior topic-specific knowledge is never tested.**"

If you knew that housecleaning comes first but the text did not say it, steel yourself from answering that way and look for some order that is strictly within the text.

To do well on such tests requires not overthinking them. A Scot might suffer on the test for knowing the order of the day, as that would surely introduce ambiguity. These tests, however, spell out unambiguously that you are to use your reasoning based only on the text supplied. What you see is what you get.

**Use the first tradition that the text lists** unless it spells out a different order (say, "The first tradition, even earlier in the day of New Year's Eve").

The text says "in China" things happen the "day before" and "before midnight." Even if you were absolutely sure the Scots do the same and that other countries copied, you will be marked wrong for using that broad knowledge. Call it a trap of the test if you will, but mark the answer that the test wants.